# How to add new Prometheus Targets

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, prometheus, monitoring, amazon-eks

I have installed Prometheus using [prometheus community](https://prometheus-community.github.io/helm-charts) on my EKS cluster.

Everything is working as expected. However I want it to scrape data from other sources. How do I add new targets? Can't find a documentation for it. Please help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Prometheus has a [scraping configuration](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#scrape_config) that allows you to add target you want to scrape. This is the documentation (a good starting point).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I actually fixed it mapping these configs by editing the configmap.